# Laravelインストーラーでプロジェクトを作成するとphpunitが"Permission denied"になる

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel v5.1.4を使っています。
Laravelインストーラv1.2.1を使ってプロジェクトを作成すると以下のようにphpunitが"Permission denied"でエラーになってしまいます。どの様に対処したらよいでしょうか？

```
$ laravel -V
Laravel Installer version 1.2.1

$ laravel new project
$ cd project

$ phpunit
-bash: ./vendor/bin/phpunit: Permission denied
```

パーミッションを確認すると実行権限がありません。

```
$ ls -l ./vendor/bin
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   750  7  2 13:51 phpspec
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   930  7  2 13:51 phpunit
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3296  7  2 13:51 psysh
```

実行権限を追加してphpunitしてみましたが、新たなエラーが...

```
$ chmod +x ./vendor/bin/phpunit
$ ls -l ./vendor/bin
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   750  7  2 13:51 phpspec
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff   930  7  2 13:51 phpunit
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  3296  7  2 13:51 psysh

$ phpunit
You need to set up the project dependencies using the following commands:
wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar install
```

ちなみに、composer経由でのプロジェクト作成ではphpunitはエラーになりません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

本件はインストーラのバグによるものです。
以下のように`laravel new`でプロジェクトを作成した場合に発生します。
マニュアルに書いてあるので、普通にこのコマンドを使うと思いますが、バグがあります。

```
larval new [project]
```

以下のディレクトリを削除して`composer install`を実行すると復旧します。

```
vendor/bin 
vendor/classpreloader 
vendor/phpspec 
vendor/phpunit 
vendor/psy
```

もしくは、少し時間がかかりますが、`vendor`ディレクトリ全体を削除してから`composer install`でも復旧します。こちらは細かくディレクトリを指定しなくて良いので、簡単です。

このバグを踏まない為には、インストーラを使わず`composer`を使ってプロジェクトを作成します。

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist [project]
```

■ 参考
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/gulp-tdd-phpunit-permission-denied
https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpunit-woes
※ 上記のサイトは4ヶ月前の情報です。復旧手順で`composer update`とありますが、現在はエラーになる為、`composer install`するのが正解です。

■ Issues
https://github.com/laravel/installer/pull/26
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9051
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9491

確実に開発者にバグが伝わってから、２ヶ月間は放置されてます。
最初のisuueの報告は説明もなく簡単にcloseされています。

Answer (score 0):

laravel new [プロジェクト]をするとバグの所為で権限は設定されてないらしいです。

これら削除してcomposer installしたら行けるはずです。

```
vendor/bin 
vendor/classpreloader 
vendor/phpspec 
vendor/phpunit 
vendor/psy
```

もちろん、作成の時にcomposer create-project laravel/laravelをしたら問題はありません。

一応、イッシューもあります。 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9491

Comment: バグのせいでとありますが、Issueが報告されている等でしょうか？そのURLが記載されていると、後から見た人がより詳しい情報を得るのに役立つと思います。

Comment: @unarist
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9491
これがあります。
前にも同じイッシューが出てましたが修正されなくてもclosedされました。今のはどうなるんでしょうか。

Comment: `composer update`だと`pre-update-cmd`で起動される`php artisan clear-compiled`がエラーになります

Comment: 現在composer installが必要らしいです。